# Why are those strings not equal?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

```
 NSLog(@"%@",variable);
 temp = @"(null)";
 if([variable  isEqualToString:temp])
```

This is the code that I use and as output I get

> [4298:207] (null)

But of course for some reason they are not equal. It's beyond me to understand this.
Both variables are of type NSString.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(null)` is just the output the `%@` format specifier gives when the value is `nil`. What is in `variable` is `nil`, not the literal string `(null)`

Comment: thank you. solved my problem already. I will accept as answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you do not understand, is because you mix two things that are not the same. Yet, when when we use written language and describe those two things, they seem the same on paper/on screen..at least to you.

First you must understand the difference between description/**label** and **meaning**.

If I write NULL ...what you see visually is a description. What does it describe / represent / mean? NULL means nothing. Yet when you write code, you do not write variable = nothing.  You write variable = NULL.
Label - meaning
NULL - nothing

When you write temp = @“null“ ..you state that the temp variable has a value of  string from 4 characters and it is these four –n u l l 
Label - meaning
@“null“ – a string with 4 characters (n u l l )

Then you compare **meanings/values.**, not descritions. Obviously ..nothing is not equal to a string with 4 characters.